# Python SSL and Unicode domains

Tags: python, ssl, unicode

I'm trying to establish a SSL connections to SSL enabled domain to check that their SSL configuration is correct, I am using the following code, I was hoping it would work with unicode domains (With the first line) but I'm still having the same issue (The original FQDN is the fqdn stored as a utf-8 string

```
fqdn = bytes(fqdn, encoding="utf-8").decode("idna")
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.check_hostname = True
context.load_default_certs()
conn = context.wrap_socket(socket.socket(socket.AF_INET),
                                server_hostname=fqdn)
conn.connect((fqdn, 443))
```

When trying to connect, I'm getting this error if this is a unicode domain :

```
hostname 'xxx-gästewohnung-xxxbühl.ch' doesn't match 'xn--xxx-gstewohnung-xxxbhl-44b50d.ch'
```

How can I fix this so the domain will match correctly ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks like a bug for me. From my understanding the code in SSLSocket explicitly decodes the given name from IDNA to unicode. From [Modules/_ssl.c](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Modules/_ssl.c#L607):

```
585 newPySSLSocket(PySSLContext *sslctx, PySocketSockObject *sock,
...
607         PyObject *hostname = PyUnicode_Decode(server_hostname, strlen(server_hostname),
608                                              "idna", "strict");
```

But, the check in [Lib/ssl.py](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Lib/ssl.py#L240) instead expects the names to be IDNA encoded:

```
219 def _dnsname_match(dn, hostname, max_wildcards=1):
...
240    if not wildcards:
241        return dn.lower() == hostname.lower()
...
250    elif leftmost.startswith('xn--') or hostname.startswith('xn--'):
```

Adding some prints for debugging in the code shows that `dn` in this function contains the IDNA encoded name while `hostname` is UTF-8 encoded and thus the comparison in line 241 does not match. Given that the code in SSLObject explicitly decodes the name from IDNA I see no way to work around this problem.

Comment: Hmm I think you are right, I found a related issue on Python : http://bugs.python.org/issue28414